# How to read a file in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, filereader

Is it possible to read files in AngularJS? I want to place the file into an HTML5 canvas to crop.

I was thinking of using a directive? This is the javascript code I want to put into my directive:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, directives is a right way, but it looks little bit different:

```
.directive("ngFileSelect",function(){    
  return {
    link: function($scope,el){          
      el.bind("change", function(e){          
        $scope.file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
        $scope.getFile();
      });          
    }        
  }
})
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/y5n16v?p=preview

Thanks to lalalalalmbda for [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/03/building-a-filereader-service-for-angularjs-the-service.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to read a file without the "change" event? For example when Edit button is clicked to open a bootstrap modal and the value is set to the input file coming from the previous loaded data?

Answer (score 12):

I've taken Cherniv's code and folded all of it into a directive:

```
.directive('fileSelect', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
            var fileReader = new $window.FileReader();

            fileReader.onload = function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(fileReader.result);

                if ('fileLoaded' in attr) {
                    scope.$eval(attr['fileLoaded']);
                }
            };

            fileReader.onprogress = function (event) {
                if ('fileProgress' in attr) {
                    scope.$eval(attr['fileProgress'], 
                    {'$total': event.total, '$loaded': event.loaded});
                }
            };

            fileReader.onerror = function () {
                if ('fileError' in attr) {
                    scope.$eval(attr['fileError'], 
                    {'$error': fileReader.error});
                }
            };

            var fileType = attr['fileSelect'];

            el.bind('change', function (e) {
                var fileName = e.target.files[0];

                if (fileType === '' || fileType === 'text') {
                    fileReader.readAsText(fileName);
                } else if (fileType === 'data') {
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileName);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You can then use the directive as follows:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="file.data" 
       file-select="data" 
       file-loaded="myLoaded()"
       file-error="myError($error)" 
       file-progress="myProgress($total,$loaded)">
```

Where "file.data", "myLoaded", "myError", and "myProgress" are in the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Angular File reader.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function(e) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                       scope.onReadFile({$content:e.target.result});
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsText((e.srcElement || e.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
```

Live example : [Live Run On Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/1M7DS4/)