# Pass Txt file Content from Angular front end to REST web Service Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, httprequest

I have a .txt file that contains a paragraph, and I want to pass it **from my Angular Controller** (I have it already: uploaded it via a form) as a parameter to http.get and read it in the Controller.
Any Idea?

Comment: Check this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598135/how-to-read-a-text-file-and-display-it-in-html-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
 1. https://github.com/leon/angular-upload 
 2. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload 
 3. https://github.com/uor/angular-file
 4. https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload
 5. https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare

Comment: My problem is between the call (Angular side) and the catch (REST endpoint) side, I already uploaded the file in my angular application.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var restler = require('restler');
var url = 'https://api.xxxxxxx';
var headers = {
    "Access-Token": "3xxxxxxxxxxx",

};
fs.stat("/path/file.pdf", function(err, stats) {
    restler.post(url, {
        multipart: true,
        headers: headers,
        data: {
            "File": restler.file("/path/file.pdf", null, stats.size, null, "application/pdf")
        }
    }).on("complete", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```