# Upload any text file and preview using only HTML5 and AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How to upload document of any type like .txt, jpeg or gif and get preview in html page? Only by using HTML5 and AngularJS. No need to save document at any location.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be good to show the code you've been working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use the FileReader API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001254/4297364) to read the data in the file.

This example modifies the above linked answer and checks if the file type is an image and displays it as such. Otherwise, it displays the file's data as text.

```js
angular.module('fileLoad', []).directive('fileSelect', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      var fileReader = new $window.FileReader();
      var fileType;
      fileReader.onload = function() {
        var fileData = {};
        fileData.type = fileType;
        fileData.data = fileReader.result;

        ctrl.$setViewValue(fileData);
        $scope.$apply();
      };

      el.bind('change', function(e) {
        var fileName = e.target.files[0];
        fileType = (fileName && fileName.type) || '';
        if (fileType.indexOf('image') != -1) {
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileName);
        } else if(fileName) {
          fileReader.readAsText(fileName);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setViewValue({});
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fileLoad">
  <input type="file" ng-model="file.data" file-select>
  <img ng-show="file.data.type && file.data.type.indexOf('image') != -1" data-ng-src="{{file.data.data}}" />
  <p ng-show="file.data.type && file.data.type.indexOf('image') == -1" ng-bind="file.data.data"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is HTML and java script.But i need in Angular Js.Please help me ASAP